# css overlay issue

Tags: jquery, css

Hi guys how can I get the red overlay to slide behind the content rather than with the content? http://jsfiddle.net/MZL5q/3/

I am trying with:

```
.transparent_layer{
background: url('../images/overlay_repeat.png') repeat-y 0 0;
width:810px;
margin:0 auto;
padding-top: 14px;
height:0;
z-index: -99999;
background-color:red;
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out this http://jsfiddle.net/MZL5q/13/

CSS

```
.behind-layer {
    background: url('../images/overlay_repeat.png') repeat-y 0 0;
    width:810px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top: 14px;
    height:0;
    z-index: 1;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
}

.transparent_layer {
    width:810px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
```

JS

```
$('.behind-layer').animate({
  height: '670'
}, 5000, function() {
  // Animation complete.
  alert('completed');
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="behind-layer"></div>
<div class="transparent_layer">
<!-- THE REST OF HTML CONTENT -->
```

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheJoeFletch/MZL5q/5/)

You need to make another div to animate with the `transparent_layer` class and make it `position:absolute;`.

For your information, if this is not at the top of your page in your production version of the site, then you may need to change some positioning aspects of the `div`'s. I read this tutorial many many times. [CSS Positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/).